# Django media files not loading when debug is False on Cpanel

Tags: django, deployment, cpanel, django-media

I am trying to show my media files for over a week and tried all stackoverflow solutions yet nothing. My project is hosted on Cpanel, i tried giving the media the absolute path, tried to put them on the public_html folder, nothing. Plus my static files are served without issue, but the media files doesn't even show in the source in developer tools (in normal case there should be one there), when debug is true it works perfectly fine but when debug is false it does not. Any ideas please?

### [image]

part of my settings.py

```
import os
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = config('CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = config('SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE')


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
    ]


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '0.0.0.0']
```

project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('panier/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('commande/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('coupon/', include('coupons.urls', namespace='coupons'))

]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    if settings.DEBUG == True:
        import debug_toolbar
        urlpatterns += [path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),]
```

some of my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
from django.db.models import F
from django.conf import settings
import os
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe



PRODUCT_STATUS = (
    ('N', 'Nouveau'),
    ('P', 'Promotion'),
    ('S', 'Sans Status')
)


@deconstructible
class PathAndRename(object):
   def __init__(self, sub_path):
       self.path = sub_path

   def __call__(self, instance, filename):
       
       filename = 'product_{0}_{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
       # return the whole path to the file
       return os.path.join(self.path, filename)

def solution_directory_path(instance, filename):
    date_fields = str(datetime.date.today()).split('-')
    year = date_fields[0]
    month = date_fields[1]
    day = date_fields[2]
    
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/solutions/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/solution_id_<filename>
    solution_sub_path = 'solutions/{0}/{1}/{2}/solution_{3}_{4}'.format(year, month, day, instance.id, filename)
    solution_full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, solution_sub_path)
    if os.path.exists(solution_full_path):
        os.remove(solution_full_path)
    return solution_sub_path

def product_directory_path(instance, filename):
    
    date_fields = str(datetime.date.today()).split('-')
    year = date_fields[0]
    month = date_fields[1]
    day = date_fields[2]
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/produits/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/produit_<produit_id>_<filename>
    product_sub_path = 'produits/{0}/{1}/{2}/product_{3}_{4}'.format(year, month, day,instance.product_id, filename)
    product_full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, product_sub_path)
    if os.path.exists(product_full_path):
        os.remove(product_full_path)
    return product_sub_path

def product_directory_path_second_picture(instance, filename):
    
    date_fields = str(datetime.date.today()).split('-')
    year = date_fields[0]
    month = date_fields[1]
    day = date_fields[2]
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/produits/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/produit_<produit_id>_<filename>
    product_sub_path = 'produits/{0}/{1}/{2}/product_{3}_photo_2_{4}'.format(year, month, day,instance.product_id, filename)
    product_full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, product_sub_path)
    if os.path.exists(product_full_path):
        os.remove(product_full_path)
    return product_sub_path

def product_file_directory_path(instance, filename):
    
    date_fields = str(datetime.date.today()).split('-')
    year = date_fields[0]
    month = date_fields[1]
    day = date_fields[2]
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/produits/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/produit_<produit_id>_<filename>
    product_sub_path = 'fichers/{0}/{1}/{2}/product_{3}_{4}'.format(year, month, day,instance.product_id, filename)
    product_full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, product_sub_path)
    if os.path.exists(product_full_path):
        os.remove(product_full_path)
    return product_sub_path


# custom product manager : have to use it for search filtering
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
            return super(ProductManager, self).get_queryset()\
                    .filter(stock__gte=1, available=True)

class Solution(models.Model):
    
    name         = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    slug        = models.SlugField( max_length=70) 
    photo       = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Photo de la solution', upload_to=solution_directory_path, blank=True)
    photo_2     = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Photo 2 de la solution', upload_to=solution_directory_path, blank= True)
    description = RichTextField(verbose_name='Text en plus', blank= True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("produit", args=[self.slug])

class Category(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Catégorie'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Catégories'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product-by-cat", args = [self.slug])
    

class Product(models.Model):
    
    product_id  = models.CharField(max_length= 50, blank=False, null= False, unique=True, default='',verbose_name='Numéro du Produit')
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name = 'Nom du Produit', db_index=True)
    slug        = models.SlugField(max_length=70, verbose_name= 'Slug')
    solution    = models.ForeignKey(Solution, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Solution', default='', null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="products" ,verbose_name='Catégorie')
    sub_title  = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=("Sous titre"), blank= True)
    description = RichTextField(verbose_name='Description', blank= True, null=True)
    sup_info    = RichTextField(verbose_name='Informations Supplémentaires', blank= True, null=True)
    photo       = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Photo du Produit', upload_to= product_directory_path, blank=True)
    photo_2     = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Photo du Produit 2', upload_to= product_directory_path_second_picture, blank=True)
    file_1   = models.FileField(verbose_name='Fiche Technique', upload_to=product_file_directory_path, blank= True)
    price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Prix', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators = [MinValueValidator(0)], blank=False, null=False)
    available = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Disponibilité', default=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices= PRODUCT_STATUS, max_length=50, default='S' , blank=False, null = False, verbose_name="Status")
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Date de Création', auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Date de dernière mise à jour', auto_now=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Stock', validators= [MinValueValidator(0)], default=0, blank=False, null=False ) 
    
    
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    show = ProductManager() # Our custom manager
    
    class Meta:
            ordering = ('name',)
            verbose_name = 'Produit'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Produits'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("produits", args=[self.slug])
    
    def get_description(self):
        return mark_safe(self.description)
    
    def get_sup_info(self):
        return mark_safe(self.sup_info) 


class ContactForm(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nom complet', max_length=100)
    phone       = models.CharField(verbose_name="Téléphone" , max_length=25)
    email       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email", null=True, blank = True)
    subject     = models.CharField(verbose_name="Sujet", max_length=50, blank=False)
    message     = models.TextField(verbose_name="Sujet", blank=False, null=False)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date", auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Formulaire de Contact'




class Post(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Image' ,upload_to='slides/', blank= True)
    text = RichTextField(verbose_name='Article', blank= True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use whitenoise to serve your media files: https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise/issues/62 You'll need to configure your server to have apache or nginx or something similar serve those media files from your media directory.

Comment: Can we serve with apache on shared hosting like Cpanel?

Comment: I would imagine so. I'm not familiar with cPanel, but I believe I've heard of folks using it to server static content. If you can set that up, then you can wire Django to upload the media files to that directory so they are accessible to the web.